# xflock4 : why button Changer user is disabled after resume?

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, lock-screen

On xubuntu 20.04.1 (multi user), since the installation (2 weeks) I have a problem with xflock4 :
After resuming from suspend, the lock screen has a problem : the Changer user button is disabled (writing the password is ok)
But the Alt C shortcut  works fine !
So if the user that resume the PC is different than the user who suspend the PC, there is no
simple solution to re-open a session.

Other problem : when I change the user, I often have to write my password twice (when a session is open) : the fist time, the deskop show for 1 s and return to screen lock.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.